# Filter Object using Lodash

Tags: filter, boolean, lodash

I started learning Lodash and want to filter the following:

```
{ 
 Cat:false,
 Dog: true,
 Fish:false
}
```

I can filter for truth values through the following:

```
filtered = _.pick(obj, function(value, key) {return value;})
```

How would I filter for objects with only false values?

Comment: maybe your usage of pick is not correct, i think you mean `pickBy` instead  https://jsfiddle.net/yesqer75/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filtered = _.pickBy(obj, function(value, key) {return !value;})
```

Or on the contrary,

```
filtered = _.omitBy(obj, function(value, key) {return value;})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is no need of predicate, you can write it shorter:

```js
const obj = {cat:false, dog:true, fish:false}

_.omitBy(obj)
// or
_.pickBy(obj, o => !o)
// or
_.pickBy(obj, _.negate(_.identity))
```